# Hyperlink Formula

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

This may be a simple issue but it's starting to become a pain in the rear for me! I have a column in excel that contains Hyperlink formulas, that links to a separate workbook (Comments.xlsm). Both workbooks are stored in the same location.

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("[Comments.xlsm]'Sheet1'!A"&MATCH(A2,'C:\Users\user\Desktop\[Comments.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A:$A,0)+1,A2),"No Data")
```

The links work fine when the other workbook is open, but when it is closed, the links become deactivated (text remains). Any ideas on how to address this? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the first reference  [Comments.xlsm] to include the full path (as you have in the second case?)  :'C:\Users\user\Desktop[Comments.xlsm]Sheet1'
?

Answer (score 0):

The text for the hyperlink cannot be in a closed workbook, so construct the hyperlink text in a helper cell, where formulas referencing external closed files will still work. Then refer to that local cell in the hyperlink function.